# Join 3 Tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

I'm trying to join 3 tables together with an inner join. Tables prod_num and usrs are relted by usr_Id and tables usrs and usr_Data are related by usr_Num. So tables 1 and 3 are not related in between so I want to realte the result of joining 1 and 2 with table 3 this is what im trying to do:

```
USE Puzzle
SELECT a.Name, a.Id, b.Id, c.Email
FROM prod_num a INNER JOIN usrs b
ON a.usr_Num = b.usr_Num<br>FROM usrs b INNER JOIN usr_Data c
ON b.usr_Id = c.usr_Id
```

How can I do a Join from a result of a previous Join?

Answer (score 4):

You should only use one `FROM` keyword because `JOIN`s are part of the `FROM` clause,

```
SELECT  a.Name, 
        a.Id, 
        b.Id, 
        c.Email
FROM    prod_num a 
        INNER JOIN usrs b 
            ON a.usr_Num = b.usr_Num
        INNER JOIN usr_Data c
            ON b.usr_Id = c.usr_Id
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
USE Puzzle
SELECT a.Name, a.Id, b.Id, c.Email
FROM prod_num a
INNER JOIN usrs b ON a.usr_Num = b.usr_Num
INNER JOIN usr_Data c ON b.usr_Id = c.usr_Id
```

You have an extra `FROM` clause between your `JOIN` statements.

Answer (score 2):

> You can do this:

```
USE Puzzle
SELECT 
     a.Name, 
     a.Id, 
     b.Id, 
     c.Email
FROM prod_num a 
INNER JOIN usrs b ON a.usr_Num = b.usr_Num
INNER JOIN usr_Data c ON b.usr_Id = c.usr_Id
```